# where to put css folder in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php with codeigniter.
my css folder is within the project folder like this localhost/project/css/main.css but still my view.php cant accessing that main.css
it doesn't give me any error. but when i tried to show incept elements in that in the console bar it shows me error 404 for css file. that is recourse not find while it is available at that location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: now on that view on a button click i had write code to redirect it to another controller.. that controller is loaded but it shows me localhost's home page

Comment: did you change $config['base_url']  in config/config.php?

Comment: cant getting you. 'yourdomain'??

Comment: got solution i had change this line in .htaccess : RewriteRule ^(.*)$ finalProjectWork/index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: again same problem in my another view because it will visit from this path http://localhost/finalProjectWork/admin_home_controller/users so again that css not found problem.. again what changes i have to make in .htaccess file?

Comment: please help me what changes i have to perform in .htaccess file

Comment: can you write your htaccess file code and error here

Comment: .htaccess is same as above error : failed to load resource : http://localhost/finalProjectwork/admin_home-controller/css/main.css

Comment: as index.php is removed from url now how to remove admin_home_controller from url to access that css folder

Comment: no in another view that redirect from this admin_home_controller/user

Comment: you must add css file into all view
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/main.css');?>" />`

Comment: done.. thank you.. actually am accessing css file directly with /css/main.css instead of using base_url().. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I like to deal with assets.

I create an helper called assets_helper in application/helpers/

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('css'))
{
    function css($nom)
    {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . base_url() . 'assets/css/' . $nom . '.css " type="text/css" media="screen" />';
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('css_print'))
{
    function css_print($nom)
    {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . base_url() . 'assets/css/' . $nom . '.css " type="text/css" media="print" />';
    }
}
//This is only the part that handle css as it is what's bothering you
```

Here is the full helper I use : http://pastebin.com/ujETEXJ4

After that, at the same level as index.php I create those folder :

```
|-Application
|-System
|-index.php
|-Assets
    |- css
    |- sass
    |- images
    |- js
```

Put all the css file you need in your new css folder.

In my application/config/autoload.php I add my new helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('assets', ...);
```

Finally, in the header of my page(s) :

```
<?php echo css('mycss'); ?> //I did not forgot the extension, it's how it works :)
```

Which will give at the end :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/assets/css/mycss.css" />
```

This way i can easly load any ressource in my code :

```
css('mycss'); //load css
css_print('mycss'); //css media="print"
js('myjs'); //load js
img('myimg.png') //img tag
img_url('myimg.png') //path to an image
```

**EDIT :**

To make it work, make sure you have correctly set your base_url in application/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/myawesomesite/";
//No index.php, don't forget the trailing slash!
```

Don't forget also to load the url helper in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'assets');
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the view part that is not working.

Comment: now done.. my mistake was i had write <? echo css('main.css') ?>, thank you :)

Comment: Indeed, simple but annoying mistake. Make sure to mark as accepted the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/main.css');?>" />
```

Comment: show me error call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: you change this line in config/autoload.php $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: still same problem as above

Comment: check your .htaccess file.
use this code in .htaccess

[link](http://justpaste.it/jmna)

Comment: link is not available to me

Comment: .htcaccess file : <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /finalProject/index.php/$1 [L]  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: While this answers the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess should be like,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /finalProjectWork/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: give me this error : Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: i have edited it check it now, moreover in your config file check this line it should be like i have written here $config['index_page'] = '';